# UISlider min and max image "Ringer and Alerts" in Settings -> Sound

Tags: ios

I want the min and max images from the "Ringer and Alerts" slider in Settings->Sound. With the UIBarButtonItem, I can be set the "Identifier, so that an image appears for things like reply and add. On this bases, I can I do the same for UISlider to look like the one in "Ringers and Alert" either programmatically or through the Interface Builder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't ask these questions on SO, or better not at all. The good old way of taking a screenshot and then selecting and copying the icons you need works perfectly fine. For better results download the UIKit Extractor: https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: But I don't want to control the system volume. I just want the min and max images.

Comment: The slider in the Sound preference pane is a normal UISlider with no images

Comment: No, it has min volume image and max volume image in iOS 4 and iOS 5.

Comment: omg and you are asking for this on SO? Ill update my answer please accept it.

Comment: For your information, I was well aware I could just screenshot it, but there will be a problem with quality when it comes to iPhone 4 and iPad(3). I was asking if there was a progamatic way or an interface builder way of setting it like with UIButtons, which I think you'll find is something I can ask on SO.

Comment: There is no programatic way of achieve this: "I want the min and max images from the "Ringer and Alerts" slider in Settings->Sound" I just tried to help so download the UIkit Extractor and then add two UIImageViews. Simplest thing in the world theres no need at all to ask a question about images on SO! And thanks for the down vote btw, thats what i get when i try to help and try to improve the quality of future questions?

Comment: I said what I wanted, but I also asked if there was a programtic way or interface builder way to do it, like UIButton. Also you should beaware that I don't need two UIImageViews as UISlider provides it. You may have been helpful especially about the UIKit Artwork Extractor, but it doesn't make my question an less invalid.

Comment: I can see that I got a little confused. It was not UIButton but UIBarButtonItem, which by setting the "identifier" it would change the button, which are images. Hence, is not correct to ask this question on the assumption that UISlider may do the same thing?